# How to update another table table after SQL insert with trigger

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin, sql-update, sql-insert, triggers

I'm a bit stuck with SQL triggers. (in Phpmyadmin), I looked how to fix my problem already in stackoverflow, but I couldn't find an answer

I have a table in database, named "items", it has rows- ID, name, price, section_ID, number (how much I got).
other table is "actions", and it has rows- ID, when_inserted, which_table, actions_type_ID (insert, update, delete. like that), user_ID.

So, for what do I need the trigger? After the update in table "items", i need to create new record in table "actions", with new ID, e.c. (table "actions" is for inserting every action what has been done on the database, from what person, and when)

Yes, I know that this question might be answered already, but I couldn't find it. If you can help me and give a link to where I can follow trough and do what I need, then- please do so. If you can answer with syntax, that would be awesome.

And sorry about my bad English.

Answer (score 0):

you need to create triggers on table items for each operation one for insert one for update and one for delete

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `insertItems`;
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER `insertItems` AFTER UPDATE ON `items`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
INSERT INTO  actions (when_inserted, which_table, actions_type_ID) VALUES (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'items', 'update');
END
//
DELIMITER ;
```

and so on

hope this helps